# What games did NVIDIA come through on regarding RTX and DLSS?

Tags: pc, hardware, graphics-card

In 2018 NVIDIA released its RTX 2000-series cards. A huge part of this release was an emphasis on some fundamental new features that games would support in the future. A list can be seen [here](https://www.game-debate.com/news/27425/every-game-with-confirmed-nvidia-rtx-ray-tracing-and-dlss-support) of these promises; particularly of note would be RTX (ray-tracing) support and DLSS (a new type of anti-aliasing) support. I know for a fact that some of these games never came through (like PUBG)... but which of these games successfully implemented these technologies as of January 2020?

Comment: Minecraft has RTX and DLSS 2.0 support as of late april.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Games that currently support:
*Deep Learning Super-Sampling* AND *RTX ray tracing*:

- Metro Exodus <sup>[1](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/battlefield-v-metro-exodus-ray-tracing-dlss/)</sup>
- Battlefield V <sup>[1](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/battlefield-v-metro-exodus-ray-tracing-dlss/)</sup>.
- Shadow of the Tomb Raider <sup>[3](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/shadow-of-the-tomb-raider-nvidia-rtx-update-out-now/)</sup>
- Wolfenstein: Youngblood <sup>[4](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/wolfenstein-youngblood-ray-tracing-nvidia-dlss-highlights/)</sup>
- Control <sup>[8](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/control-rtx-ray-tracing-dlss-out-now/)</sup>

## DLSS only:

- Anthem <sup>[5](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/anthem-nvidia-dlss-highlights/)</sup>
- Final Fantasy XV (Windows Edition) <sup>[6](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/final-fantasy-xv-dlss-game-ready-driver/)</sup>
- Monster Hunter: World <sup>[2](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/monster-hunter-world-nvidia-dlss/)</sup>

## RTX ray tracing only:

- Call of Duty: Modern Warfare <sup>[7](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-pc-out-now-with-ray-tracing/)</sup>
- Quake II RTX <sup>[9](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1089130/Quake_II_RTX/)</sup>
- Stay in the Light <sup>[10](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1081330/Stay_in_the_Light/)</sup>

Both features are also supported by the Port Royal 3DMark benchmark <sup>[11](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/nvidia-dlss-3dmark-port-royal-benchmark/)</sup>.

Comment: Monster Hunter World, as far as I have googled, does not offer any kind of raytracing, except when being modded to do so, but it supports DLSS.

Comment: @Crovaxon Thanks for catching that: the article linked confirms your claim.

Comment: Also look at [here](https://in.ign.com/cd-projekt-red-project-untitled/150484/news/50-games-with-rtx-and-dlss) and [here](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2020/10/20/confirmed-ray-tracing-and-dlss-games-2020/). Too numerous for me to edit the post.